# How to automatically load a cmo in utop

Tags: ocaml

I have built my own `graph.cmo`.

I would like `utop`  automatically load it every time I launch it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ocamlinit` in your home directory also works with `utop`.

```
nlucaroni@pissarro: ~ $ cat ~/.ocamlinit 
#load "graph.cmo";;
let () = Printf.printf "LOADED!";;

nlucaroni@pissarro: ~ $ utop
Welcome to utop version 1.11 (using OCaml version 4.01.0)!                           
        Camlp4 Parsing version 4.01.0

LOADED!
Type #utop_help for help about using utop.

utop #
```

Comment: do you write `#load "path/a.cmo"` inside?

Comment: you bet! Sorry, I had assumed you were doing this already and had known.